# Warning with command in math mode

Tags: math-mode

I'm getting warnings with this code:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item $U'_0$, $all$, and $all'$.
    \item For all $1\leq i\leq n$ we have agents $x_i$ and $¬x_i$.
    \item For all $1\leq i\leq m$ we have agents $y_i$ and $¬y_i$.
    \item For all $1\leq j\leq k$ we have agent $c_j$.
    \item For all $1\leq i\leq n+m$ we have agent $col_i$.
\end{itemize}
```

I tried to add `\usepackage{amsmath}` but still getting the warning using `\leq` command.

[image]

Is any other library necessary?

Comment: the issue is with ¬, use \neg instead and it should be fine

Comment: oh, I tho it was some problem with \leq. Tysm!

Comment: No problem, errors are not easy to read

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fix is simple: declare `¬` to behave as `\lnot` in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00AC}{\TextOrMath{\textlnot}{\lnot}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item $U'_0$, $\mathit{all}$, and $\mathit{all}'$.
    \item For all $1\leq i\leq n$ we have agents $x_i$ and $¬x_i$.
    \item For all $1\leq i\leq m$ we have agents $y_i$ and $¬y_i$.
    \item For all $1\leq j\leq k$ we have agent $c_j$.
    \item For all $1\leq i\leq n+m$ we have agent $\mathit{col}_i$.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

I also added `\mathit` around the multiletter identifiers, because I believe `all` and `col` are not supposed to be multiplications of three variables.

You might also simply redeclare

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00AC}{\lnot}
```

if you want the symbol to only appear in math mode and raise an error otherwise.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For this specific case, the *warning* mentions `\textlnot` [is] invalid in math mode. So, put it outside of math mode:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item $U'_0$, $\mathrm{all}$, and $\mathrm{all}'$.
  \item For all $1 \leq i \leq n$ we have agents $x_i$ and ¬$x_i$.
  \item For all $1 \leq i \leq m$ we have agents $y_i$ and ¬$y_i$.
  \item For all $1 \leq j \leq k$ we have agent $c_j$.
  \item For all $1 \leq i \leq n + m$ we have agent $\mathrm{col}_i$.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

However, in general, you can/should use `\neg` to negate boolean variables:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item $U'_0$, $\mathrm{all}$, and $\mathrm{all}'$.
  \item For all $1 \leq i \leq n$ we have agents $x_i$ and $\neg x_i$.
  \item For all $1 \leq i \leq m$ we have agents $y_i$ and $\neg y_i$.
  \item For all $1 \leq j \leq k$ we have agent $c_j$.
  \item For all $1 \leq i \leq n + m$ we have agent $\mathrm{col}_i$.
\end{itemize}
```